# Almacenar dos campos distintos en javascript con ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

hago una consulta ajax y recorro con un bucle for la respuesta. Me devuelve dos ids pero quiero recojer uno por uno. Si en un futuro tengo 5 ids quiero tener los ids en distintas th. Estos ids son para th dinámicos os paso el bucle

```html
$.ajax({
                    url: '',
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: '',
                    async: false,
                    success: function(response){ 
                        var nom = JSON.parse(response);
                        console.log(nom)
                        for (var x = 0; x<nom.length; x++){
                            ids=nom[x].id
                            console.log(ids)
                        }
```

La respuesta es id:1, id:2

Es como almacenar cada id generado en una misma variable pero sin repetirse

Comment: Puedes guardarlas en un array

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Además, para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Para esto último, ¿podrías poner un ejemplo de datos que te devuelve para poder reproducir tu problema? La solución es sencilla, pero necesito datos de entrada de ejemplo para mostrarte el funcionamiento.

Comment: Además, si quieres crear un `<th>` por cada identificador, ¿podrías compartir cómo deseas hacerlo? Quizá entendiendo mejor cómo quieres usar estos datos podríamos ayudarte a obtener la información tal y como la necesitas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar la función [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) para obtener todos las propiedades `id` de cada elemento de la matriz que has recibido:

```js
//let nom = JSON.parse(response);
let nom = [
  { id: 5, nombre: "Pepito" },
  { id: 2, nombre: "Manuelita" },
  { id: 8, nombre: "Manolito" },
  { id: 1, nombre: "Joselito" }
];
console.log("IDs:", nom.map(elemento => elemento.id));
```